# ggplot2: points and lines in legend when there are no points on figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]Is it possible to have both plots and lines on the legend without any points actually on the plot?

For example, I have:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
    time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

library(ggplot2)
lp1 <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex, colour=sex)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size = 2.5)
lp1

lp1 + scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                        breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                        labels=c("Woman", "Man")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Payer",
                       breaks=c("Female", "Male"),
                       labels=c("Woman", "Man"))
```

I would like to remove the points from my plot, but keep it in the legend. How do I do that? I tried setting the size of geom_point to zero and also colour as NULL but it gets rid of the points from the legend. Thanks in advance for all your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `alpha = 0` in `geom_point` and later overwrite this value adding `guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))` to your plot.

```
lp1 <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex, colour=sex)) + 
        geom_line() + 
        geom_point(size = 2.5, alpha = 0)
lp1 + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image]